# codeigniter - open a page to a specific location

Tags: codeigniter

I want to direct viewers to a location on a page with something like mydomain.com/page.html#intro.

How do I specify it in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.  Never mind.  Just had to add the #intro to the referring link.

Guess I was looking for something more complicated.